# Add file into hidden folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to add a file from the host machine to the container into a hidden folder but it does not seem to be working. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM frekele/gradle:2.14.1-jdk8

MAINTAINER Fran Garcia <myemail@email.com>

ADD gradle.properties /root/.gradle/gradle.properties

# Run
CMD ["ls", "/root/.gradle/gradle.properties"]
```

But the file is not added. I can add this file to any other folder but not to a hidden one. Does anybody have any idea why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please add the commands that you use to build, run and enter the image/container? It's very hard to understand what you're asking without that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as designed. Your error is in the way you use the `CMD`. Here's what's happening:

- I created your Dockerfile, and then ran `docker build . -t gr-foo`
- I started the container using `docker run -it --rm gr-foo`, which produced the following output line (among others):

  ```
  exec: fatal: unable to exec ls /root/.gradle/gradle.properties: No such file or directory
  ```

I guess this is the error that you're seeing as well.

The `CMD` expects an array of values, where each entry is treated as one part of the command line. You need to change it to:

```
CMD ["ls", "/root/.gradle/gradle.properties"]
```

This will treat `ls` and the path as two different items, resulting in the desired output:

```
/root/.gradle/gradle.properties
ls exited 0
```

Comment: Ok, that is fine, but if you ssh to the container, the file I tried to copy at /root/.gradle is not there. I am going to update the question to avoid confusion. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just tried this, and SSH'ed into the container - the file is there, as expected.

Comment: Yes, I have also realised of it! There has to be something wrong as when using it in a docker compose yml file (which is the real way I was using the container), the file is not copied. I am investigating the reason. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working in the basic setup. For the Docker Compose case, I suggest you create a new question that includes the `docker-compose.yaml` file and the command that you use to run the containers.